# Call external function written in C from another file written in C in a Linux enviroment

Tags: c

I am having trouble calling an external function I wrote in the Pico editor in linux. The program should call an external function and they are both written in C.

```
#include????

void calcTax()
float calcfed()
float calcssi()
```

---

// stub program

```
#include"FILE2"???or do I use"./FILE2"// not sure which to use here or what        extension     the file should have. .c or .h and if it is .h do I simply change the file     name to file.h?
#include<stdio.h>
#define ADDR(var) &var

extern void calctaxes()
int main()
{
}
```

I am using gcc to compile but it will not compile. both files are in the same directory and have the .c extension

I am a new student so bear with me.

Comment: That `ADDR` macro looks pretty heinous - watch out for that one.

Comment: It sounds like you should take a step back and instead read up on what compilers and linkers do.  Once you understand the relationship between translation units and executable code, the answer will be obvious.

Comment: I removed the mention of pico from the title; it doesn't matter what editor you use to create your source files. I also removed the C++ tag; C and C++ are two different languages, and you're using C.

Answer (score 5):

Normally, when you want a function in one compilation unit to call a function in another compilation unit, you should create a header file containing the function prototypes.  The header file can be included in both compilation units to make sure that both sides agree on the interface.

calctax.h

```
#ifndef calctax_h_included
#define calctax_h_included

void calctaxes(void);
/* any other related prototypes we want to include in this header */

#endif
```

Note that `extern` is not required on functions, only global data.  Also, since the function takes no arguments, you should put `void` in the argument list, and you also need a semi-colon at the end of the prototype.

Next, we can include this header file in the .c file that implements the function:

calctax.c

```
#include "calctax.h"

void calctaxes(void)
{
    /* implementation */
}
```

Finally, we include the same header file in our main .c file that calls the function:

main.c

```
#include "calctax.h"

int main(int argc, char **argc)
{
    calctax();
    return 0;
}
```

You can compile and link these together with

```
% gcc -o main main.c calctax.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't want to include `.c` implementation files.  The normal thing to do is have two source files that you build into objects:

```
cc -o file1.o file1.c
cc -o file2.o file2.c
```

And then link them into an executable at the end:

```
cc -o example file1.o file2.o
```

To allow calling functions between the two `.c` files, you create a header (`.h`) file that has function declarations for everything you're interested in sharing.  For you, that might be something like `header.h`, containing:

```
void calcTax(void);
float calcfed(void);
float calcssi(void);
```

Then, just `#include "header.h"` from the implementation files where you need to know about those functions.

Comment: so I already have file1.c and file2.c, are you saying I should change them to file1.o and file2.o then compile using gcc -o file1.o file2.o?

Comment: No.  Follow the steps I described.  Compile the `.c` files into `.o` objects, then link the `.o` objects into a final executable.

Comment: Oh I think I understand... My file2.c is my function file. I should change that to have the .h extension?

Comment: Probably not, if it has the definitions in it.  Normally the header should just contain declarations.

Comment: OK, I appreciate the help but am still confused. Not your fault I just did not explain the problem correctly. file1.c(stub program), file2.c(function). do I still follow your original suggestion? forgive my ignorance.

Comment: You need to create a third file, a header file, containing the declarations of the functions that are defined in `file2.c` that you want to call from `file1.c`.